# Why should i use debug=assets to load my JS file Odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

I added a new button near the Create Button in Odoo 14 but the issue that im facing its when i remove **debug=assets** JS file can't be executed anymore
is there's way to load it instead of using **debug=assets** ??
Thank you

Comment: You have to add your js file to the assets by "linking" it into the `common_assets.xml` or `assets.xml`. There should be a lot of examples in Odoo itself. Odoo will generate an assets bundle file, with all js code which will be used outside the assets debug mode. This debug mode will load all js files directly from code (not from the bundle), what will lead to not minified and structured (you will see from which module it comes) js code in your browser dev tools.

Comment: @Farid how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @CZoellner this solution is not working for me!

Comment: But that is the [common way](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#assets-management).